# Matlab multiple entries in one legend line

Tags: matlab, plot, legend

is it possible to combine multiple plots in one legend entry as shown in the picture? I did this by using Paint but I'm looking for a way to do that in MATLAB. I tried various operations with [] and () but it didn't work.

Is there a way to put two plots in one legend entry?

[image: What I'd like to have]

Relevant code (does not what I'd like to have!)

```
clear all; close all; clc
p1=plot(1,1,'bs','MarkerFaceColor','b'); hold on;
p2=plot(2,1,'rs','MarkerFaceColor','r');
p3=plot(3,1,'rh','MarkerFaceColor','r'); hold off;
grid on;
axis([0,4,0,2]);
legend({'A','B','B'},'Location','Northeast');
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: B are both measurement results and I'm curious to know if I can sum up both of them in one legend line.

Comment: Because you can do that with python with the HandlerTuple class. See https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-intermediate-legend-guide-py

Comment: The reason is very specific. As I said, both are results from measurements but I want to highlight some of the results (by using another marker symbol e.g.) but they are still of the same category 'result', that's why I'm also using the same color.

Comment: I think you've missed the point of using a legend, if the star doesn't signify anything particularly different then don't use it. If it does signify something different then state what that is on the legend... I suspect this logic is the reason why this isn't possible (in a documented sense).

Comment: With a  less blunt head on, I'd suggest simply not using a square as either of the data points, hiding those plots from the legend (`'HandleVisibility'` set to `'off'`), then create some spoof points (not visible as plotted as NaN) with square markers, which will just be to illustrate a "block of colour" rather than a square data point. This colour corresponds to any marker of that colour. Feels a bit hack to avoid a single legend entry.

Comment: I’m with Wolfie, if there is no distinction between the red square and the red star, then don’t distinguish them, give them the same marker. If there is a distinction, you will want to make that explicit by saying what each marker represents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of a hack, not perfect though:

```
p2 = plot(2,1,'rs','MarkerFaceColor','r');  hold on
p1 = plot(1,1,'bs','MarkerFaceColor','b'); 
p3 = plot(3,1,'rh','MarkerFaceColor','r');  hold off;
grid on;
axis([0,4,0,2]);
legend({'B','A',''},'NumColumns',2,'EdgeColor',[1,1,1]);
```

This divides the legend into two columns and then there is no text for the third entry. This will result into an uneven box. So just hide the box (?).

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you all for your help!